# How can I check the quantitative relationship of constant generalizations during compilation in rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I have an enum in rust:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Level<const N1: u8, const N2: u8, const N3: u8> {
    Low,
    Medium,
    High,
    Maximum,
}
```

I would like to check the quantitative relationship during compilation that satisfies `0 < N1 < N2 < N3 < u8::MAX`

How do I implement this?

Comment: This sounds like a refinement types thing, which Rust doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not well supported in Rust currently, but you can do that by having an associated const that panics on invalid values:

```rust
impl<const N1: u8, const N2: u8, const N3: u8> Level<N1, N2, N3> {
    const VALID: () = if !(0 < N1 && N1 < N2 && N2 < N3 && N3 < u8::MAX) {
        panic!("invalid values");
    };
}
```

Then, on any function where quantitive relationship is important, do like the following:

```rust
impl<const N1: u8, const N2: u8, const N3: u8> Level<N1, N2, N3> {
    pub fn foo() {
        _ = Self::VALID;
    }
}
```

This will cause a compilation failure when the values are invalid. Beware, though, that this is a post-monomorphization error - the primary meaning is that `cargo check` will succeed, and only `cargo build` will fail.

Comment: I didn't realize that rust didn't support this feature at the moment. I appreciate your help, this is probably the best way to go at the moment